# How to show validation error message in django admin page with post_save signal?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-signals

I need to show validation error message in django admin page like a `clean` function for a django model

my post_save function:

```
@receiver(models.signals.post_save, sender=Counter)
def execute_after_save(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
  
    counter = Counter.objects.filter(order_id=instance.order_id).values('product_id').annotate(Count('pk'))

    counter = counter.values('pk__count').get()['pk__count']

    if counter is None:
        counter = 0

    if counter > 1:
        raise ValidationError("Error here")
```

Answer (score 0):

#### It is not possible to show validation error from signals body in admin page.

You can override your model's clean method for checking your conditions or your admin's class clean method. For example:

```
class Counter(models.Model):
    some_fields

    def clean(self):
        super(Counter, self).clean()
        counter = Counter.objects.filter(order_id=instance.order_id).values('product_id').annotate(Count('pk'))

        counter = counter.values('pk__count').get()['pk__count'] or 0

        if counter > 1:  # or you can decrease it to something like counter > 0
            raise ValidationError("Error here")
```

Comment: Yeah, but  model Order and Counter are creating at one time (two models on one django detail form page) and I can't get order id without post_save :(